# JQuery "looping" when replacing letters by others following character map

Tags: jquery, regex, replace, mapping, character

I'm trying to get each letter to be replaced by another one using JQuery, . There is cyphering mode and a decyphering mode. Unfortunately, only the cyphering mode seems to work. The decyphering seems to be replacing all letters by the two first letters of the character map, as if "looping". That's where I'm stuck (and yes, I'm a newbie.)

Here is a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/692455/

Here is my code so far :

```
$('#chiffrer').keyup(function (chiffrement) {
var chiffrer = {
u:'a',z:'b',b:'c',c:'d',a:'e',
d:'f',f:'g',g:'h',e:'i',h:'j',
j:'k',k:'l',l:'m',m:'n',i:'o',
n:'p',p:'q',q:'r',r:'s',s:'t',
o:'u',t:'v',v:'w',w:'x',x:'y',y:'z'
};
textechiffre = chiffrement.target.value;
for (var txt in chiffrer) {
    var temp = new RegExp(txt, 'gim');
    textechiffre = textechiffre.replace(temp, chiffrer[txt]);
    $('#resultat2').text(textechiffre);
}})

$('#dechiffrer').keyup(function (dechiffrement) {
var dechiffrer = {
a:'u',b:'z',c:'b',d:'c',e:'a',
f:'d',g:'f',h:'g',i:'e',j:'h',
k:'j',l:'k',m:'l',n:'m',o:'i',
p:'n',q:'p',r:'q',s:'r',t:'s',
u:'o',v:'t',w:'v',x:'w',y:'x',z:'y'
};
textedechiffre = dechiffrement.target.value;
for (var txt in dechiffrer) {
    var temp = new RegExp(txt, 'gim');
    textedechiffre = textedechiffre.replace(temp, dechiffrer[txt]);
    $('#resultat').text(textedechiffre);
}})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither of your functions work properly; you're changing the `textechiffre` string *while* you're looping over the encryption (or decryption) object. For example, "a" might get changed to "e", but then that same "e" may get changed to "i", etc. Use a replacer function instead:

```
$('#resultat2').text(textechiffre.replace(/[a-z]/gi, char => chiffrer[char]));
```

Full code:

```js
$('#chiffrer').keyup(function(chiffrement) {
  var chiffrer = {
    u: 'a',
    z: 'b',
    b: 'c',
    c: 'd',
    a: 'e',
    d: 'f',
    f: 'g',
    g: 'h',
    e: 'i',
    h: 'j',
    j: 'k',
    k: 'l',
    l: 'm',
    m: 'n',
    i: 'o',
    n: 'p',
    p: 'q',
    q: 'r',
    r: 's',
    s: 't',
    o: 'u',
    t: 'v',
    v: 'w',
    w: 'x',
    x: 'y',
    y: 'z'
  };
  const textechiffre = chiffrement.target.value;
  $('#resultat2').text(textechiffre.replace(/[a-z]/gi, char => chiffrer[char]));

})

$('#dechiffrer').keyup(function(dechiffrement) {
  var dechiffrer = {
    a: 'u',
    b: 'z',
    c: 'b',
    d: 'c',
    e: 'a',
    f: 'd',
    g: 'f',
    h: 'g',
    i: 'e',
    j: 'h',
    k: 'j',
    l: 'k',
    m: 'l',
    n: 'm',
    o: 'i',
    p: 'n',
    q: 'p',
    r: 'q',
    s: 'r',
    t: 's',
    u: 'o',
    v: 't',
    w: 'v',
    x: 'w',
    y: 'x',
    z: 'y'
  };
  const textedechiffre = dechiffrement.target.value;
  $('#resultat').text(textedechiffre.replace(/[a-z]/gi, char => dechiffrer[char]));
})
```

```css
body {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

textarea {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: auto;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

textarea#dechiffrer {
  outline: none;
  background: rgba(78, 182, 185, 0.2);
}

textarea#dechiffrer,
textarea#dechiffrer::placeholder {
  color: rgba(95, 158, 160, 1);
}

textarea#chiffrer {
  outline: none;
  background: rgba(205, 92, 92, 0.2);
}

textarea#chiffrer,
textarea#chiffrer::placeholder {
  color: rgba(205, 92, 92, 1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <textarea type="text" placeholder="decypher" name="dechiffrer" id="dechiffrer"></textarea>
  <textarea type="text" placeholder="cypher" name="chiffrer" id="chiffrer"></textarea>
</div>
<span id="resultat"></span><br>
<span id="resultat2"></span>
```